# Pretty URL + CSS + Command-pattern + Controller (my combination doesn't work)

Tags: php, .htaccess, regex-negation, friendly-url, command-pattern

I wish to have these pretty urls:

- Overview of all categories: localhost/category
- Form to make new category: localhost/category/new
- Form to edit category: localhost/category/edit/4

Since I'm working with the Command pattern in my Controller I have these actions in my processRequest in my Controller I have these ugly urls:

- localhost/index.php?action=categoryOverview
- localhost/index.php?action=categoryNew
- localhost/index.php?action=categoryNew&id=4

I'm trying this with .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]*) index.php?action=$1&id=$2
```

But this doesn't work + my CSS is not loading. I tried these:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css/">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css/">
```

Could you please help me how

1. these pretty urls are done correctly?
2. to have the css appear?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
```

instead of

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

So apache will try to find directories (-d) and symbolic links (-l) before passing the url to the controller.

Comment: Nope, still no css :(

Comment: The path for the css must start with / (/css/bootstrap.css)

Comment: Maybe this helps: [link](http://lifeonubuntu.com/how-to-debug-apache-rewriterule-or-mod_rewrite/)